# Prove or disprove two simple statements on conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

STATEMENT 1:

if $P[A|B]=P[B]$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent.

My attempt:

Assuming that $A$ and $B$ are independent then, since $P[A|B]= P[B]$ is possible only if $P[A]=P[B]$, the statement is not true in general.

STATEMENT 2:

if $P[A∩B|C]=P[A|C]P[B|C]$, then A and B are independent events.

I've tried many ways, but I cannot figure out how to prove or disprove the statement. Could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

HINTS

Stmt 1: you have proven the reverse direction.  You need to show a counter-example where $P(A\mid B) = P(B)$ but $A, B$ are dependent.  Instead your only showed an example where $A, B$ independent but $P(A\mid B) \neq P(B)$.  It's the wrong direction.

The correct counter-example is not difficult.  You can easily construct examples with coins, dice (or even just purely abstractly).

Stmt 2: This is more subtle.  $P(A\cap B\mid C) = P(A\mid C) P(B \mid C)$ means that $A,B$ are independent *when conditioned on $C$*.  The question is does that make $A,B$ independent when unconditioned?  I would suggest using a 6-sided die and assigning various subsets of results as $A,B,C$ and see if you can first find an example where $P(A\cap B\mid C) = P(A\mid C) P(B \mid C)$.

Hope this helps.  If you're still stuck after a while lemme know your progress and I'll see if I can think of further hints.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I found already tons of examples on the web, the problem is that I can't understand their logic. Here on math exchange for example I find this example for statement 2:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3002222/can-it-be-shown-that-pabc-pacpbc-if-a-and-b-are-independent-event?rq=1
the rationale is clear, I do not understand the number attached to those probabilities. If you could provide two easy examples explaining where the number come from it would be of great help.

Comment: what do you not understand about that example?  that's a very simple example already.  which number do you not understand?

Comment: I cannot understand what is the intersection between A and B (which are independent by the way) and why conditioning the intersection to C we get 1/2. $A∩B$ is "get H in both coins", conditioned to "the two coins match", If C happens and the two coin matches, then I have on both tails or head, then 1/2 as prob., is this the right interpretation? What does it mean $P(A|C)$? If C happens, then the two coins match what information gives about the happening of A? Finally, in the example did they prove the wrong direction?

Comment: you interpretation of $P(A\cap B \mid C)$ is entirely correctly, and now you understand why that value is $1/2$.  As for $P(A \mid C)$, you are also correct that knowing $C$ does not give you any clue about $A$.  that's why $P(A \mid C)$ remains $1/2$.  in that thread, the question asked in the reverse of your stmt 2.  so that answer correctly answered that question, but it is not the proper counter-example for your stmt 2.  you need a different example.